# No enclosing instance I need solutions

Tags: static, libgdx

Sry my bad english.
So i'm working on a game, and i have problem. (Libgdx but is does't matter)
SolarGame is a main class, that is an inputhandler.
TesterClass has a render method.
Lightning is generating some data.

```
public  class SolarGame implements  ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {
TesterClass testerClass;
bool inputbool = false; //That bool is change, when event is happen

public bool getBool(){
   return inputbool
}

public void create () {
    testerClass = new TesterClass();
}
//some other code here

public class TesterClass {

Lightning lightning;

public void _init_() {
    lightning = new Lightning();
}
//Some code here

public class Lightning {

    public Lightning() {
        bool input = SolarGame.this.getBool();
//This line cause an error.
```

If a change SolarGame to static i get some other error.
But i need to acess to inputbool, in Lightning class.
I need to stop the Lightning data genereation metod when event is happend.

Sry my english again.

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand this right u need an instance of SolarGame in your Lightning class? Because its quite hard to understand what the actual problem is, the code doesnt help much either.

What you can do to get an instance of SolarGame in Lightning is quite simple. you just pass it on when u create Lighting:

```
public class Lightning{ 

SolarGame game;

public Lightning(SolarGame game){
      this.game = game;
}
}
```

Now you can access your *inputbool* without any problems without changing any class to static:

```
bool inputbool = game.getBool();
```

Since you create the *Lightning* class in a *TesterClass* you need to pass the instance of *SolarGame* to the *TesterClass* the same way as described above.

I hope i´ve solved your problem